# Infinispan cache settings set in JBoss EAP 7.0 standalone.xml not reflected in application

Tags: java, caching, jboss, jboss7.x, infinispan

I added a cache through CLI in JBoss 7:

```
/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=sample:add
/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=sample/replicated-cache=account:add(mode=ASYNC)
/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=sample/replicated-cache=account/component=transaction:write-attribute(name=mode,value=BATCH)
/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=sample/replicated-cache=account/component=locking:write-attribute(name=isolation, value=REPEATABLE_READ)
```

Seen it reflected in standalone.xml's Infinispan subsystem:

```
<cache-container name="sample">
    <replicated-cache name="account" mode="ASYNC">
        <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
        <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
    </replicated-cache>
</cache-container>
```

Seen it reflected in JBoss console:

[image]

But when used within the application, the cache container is found, but the cache is not. Instead, it is created lazily when `cacheManager#getCache` is called with different settings set.

[image]

Mode set is replicated, but what is found is local. Other settings like transaction are also different. Did I miss something?

Comment: Hmmm, have you tried with latest JBoss/Wildfly app server, that'd be Wildfly 10.

Comment: I would love to, but my organization prohibits for now.

Comment: If I were you I'd give it a try at least with Wildfly 10 or 11 and see if it works as expected. If it does, you have a reason for your organization to upgrade. If it doesn't, maybe something else is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears caches are only eagerly initialized on depending EJB modules. Libraries backed with CDIs don't trigger cache initialization.

Answer (score 1):

I had very similar problem to you. I had a local-cache with configured lifespan in EAP 7. It was configured to be relatively short. The same configuration worked well earlier, but we realized, that the cached stuff remained in the cache forever.

The problem was how we got to the instance of the cache. We injected the cache manager:

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/download-manager")
private CacheContainer cacheContainer;
```

Then we used the cache container to access the cache. After debugging the lifespan was -1 even though the lifespan in EAP 7 was 30 seconds only.

```
cacheContainer.getCache("someCache")
```

Did not get the instance of the cache, but instead of that it created a new cache with default values. I think it explains your "local cache" only setting.

The way how I got to the cache with the proper settings was:

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/cache/download-manager/someCache")
private Cache<String, Object> negative_cache_direct;
```